# Use <ng-content> to pass HTML from parent component and display in a modal component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular2-ngcontent

I have a modal component in which is getting used in different modules. To make it dynamic, I need to pass design from a parent component from where I am calling the modal.

I tried to use ng-content to pass the design but since its a modal component, I am not sure how to pass the HTML and how it will get display in modal.

**Calling modal from component**

```
 const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: AutoCompleteModalComponent,
      cssClass: 'fullpage-modal',
    });
   
    return await modal.present();
```

The end goal is to insert the HTML (for example,`<p>Hello</p>`) in a parent component from where I am calling the modal, and that HTML should get displayed in modal. I am hoping this can be done with **ng-content** or **ng-templateoutlet**. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've no experience with ionic, but you can try the following.

In the parent component template, add a ng-template with the content to project.

```
<ng-template #myModalContent>
  <p>Hello</p>
</ng-template>
```

Grab the reference to this template with viewChild and pass it as a componentProp

```
class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChild('myModalContent') modalContent: TemplateRef;

  ...

  yourOpenModalMethod(){
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: AutoCompleteModalComponent,
      cssClass: 'fullpage-modal',
      componentProps: {
        projectedContent: this.modalContent
      }
    });

    return await modal.present();
  }
}
```

Define an Input in the modalComponent to grab the prop.

```
class AutoCompleteModalComponent {
  @Input() projectedContent: TemplateRef;
  
  ...
}
```

And finally in the modal template add a ng-container to render the template

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="projectedContent"></ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks @akotech, this solution is working